# Creating/Editing keyboard shortucts in IBM Rhapsody 7.x

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, rhapsody

I've looked in many places and I got only scarce information. So thus a question.
Is it possible to add/change/modify keyboard shortcuts for IBM Rhapsody 7.x (Architect/Developer/etc).
In particular I'm looking for a way to use the navigation menu arrows - Back and Forward from the keyboard.
thanks for any help
cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so.

Existing Shortcuts in Rational Rhapsody:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rhaphlp/v7r6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rhp.overview.doc%2Ftopics%2Frhp_c_po_access_features.html

You can create shortcuts on your own plugin:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rhaphlp/v7r6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rhp.customization.doc%2Ftopics%2Frhp_t_ext_creating_links_helper.html